# Session error when postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
        try
        {
            Label1.Text = Session["user.transaction.id"].ToString(); //Error Line
        }
        catch (Exception a8)
        {
            Label1.Text = a8.Message;
        }
 }
```

The code I used to stored information into Session

try
        {

```
        _conn = new OdbcConnection(DatabaseManager.getConnectionString());
        if (_conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            _conn.Open();
        OdbcCommand cmd = _conn.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "{call vam_gen_new_card3(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@personal_card", OdbcType.Char, 1).Value = 'Y';
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@holder_surname", OdbcType.VarChar, 50).Value = tbSurname.Text.ToString();
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@holder_name", OdbcType.VarChar, 100).Value = tbName.Text.ToString();
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@holder_cname", OdbcType.Char, 10).Value = tbCname.Text.ToString();
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@date_of_birth", OdbcType.VarChar, 11).Value = tbDOB.Text.ToString();
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@travel_document_no", OdbcType.VarChar, 20).Value = tbTravelDocNo.Text.ToString();
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@nationality", OdbcType.VarChar, 40).Value = tbNationality.Text.ToString();
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@email", OdbcType.VarChar, 50).Value = tbEmail.Text.ToString();
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@telephone", OdbcType.VarChar, 20).Value = tbTelephone.Text.ToString();
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@mobilephone", OdbcType.VarChar, 20).Value = tbMobile.Text.ToString();
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@card_remark", OdbcType.VarChar, 255).Value = card_remark;
        OdbcDataReader rs = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (rs.Read())
        {
            Session["user.transaction.id"] = "SVC0" + rs["card_no"].ToString();   //get the transaction no.
            Session["user.total_amount"] = Convert.ToDecimal(tbAmount.Text);
        }
```

I originally create the transaction id in the `Session["user.transaction.id]`. But when I post the information to the paymentgateway and post back. I cannot get back the `Session["user.transaction.id"]` and got the error. I would like to know how to fix this problem.

Comment: Your `Session["user.transaction.id"]` is null , how are you adding the value in the session

Comment: which object is null? please double check the "user.transaction.id" string.

Comment: Your `Session["user.transaction.id"]` is probably `null`. Please check it.

Comment: I adding the value of Session by using the following code: Session[user.transaction.id] = "SA12054372". It's ok and can pass to payment gateway. But when postback to the original page. I got some problem.

Comment: write code where you add that value to session

Comment: You are overwriting the value in session variable through while loop or the reader holds only one value?

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to create a session variable is:

```
Session["VarName"] = value;
```

To read item from session:

```
Label1.Text = Session["VarName"].ToString();
```

Or you can use the Add method as:

```
Session.Add("VarName", value);
```

Either way will work.

Next to remove an item from the session state:

```
Session.Remove("VarName");
```

To clear all items from the session state use:

```
Session.Clear();
```

Comment: Can some body please explain why i got negative?

Comment: I know how to use the Session to store value. But I just don't know why the Session value has lost when across pages.

Comment: oh i am sorry, i was just trying to add-on some valuable information...

Answer (score 1):

`NullReferenceException`s are far more common that they should be.

You can't call `ToString()` on nothing. You should be checking, such as:

```
if (Session["user.transaction.id"] != null) {
    Session["user.transaction.id"].ToString();
}
```

This is something you should get used to bearing in mind, and learn to not assume tat anything will be something. Just look at `Label.Text` and `a8.Message`: in these cases it's a lot more clear and 'safe' that `Label` and `a8` are things, but every time you're accessing members of a reference type you should know your variable has a reference to an instance. So, these exceptions are easy to track down.

If you're getting this problem in the process of sending your user somewhere then having them return, then it is quite possible that the users are away for a longer time than allotted for the Session timeout, hence starting a new session upon their return.

Answer (score 0):

Your session is null. YOu have to check for null value in session first then use the value exist in session variable.

try this

```
if (!IsPostBack)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (Session["user.transaction.id"] != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["user.transaction.id"].ToString()))
                        {
                            Label1.Text = Session["user.transaction.id"].ToString(); //Error Line
                        }

                    }
                    catch (Exception a8)
                    {
                        Label1.Text = a8.Message;
                    }
                }
```